# Enabled switch component with loading icon.

Tags: switch-statement, antd

In ant design, switch component can show a loading icon inside of the component.

As you can see in [this sample](https://ant.design/components/switch/#components-switch-demo-loading), when the switch component is showing the loading icon, it cannot be clickable and disabled.

my question is how can I make this enabled and showing loading icon?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/x91kmm8zz

Answer (score 0):

The onClick handler will not trigger if the switch is loading. So you'll first have to set loading={false} only then will you be able to access the switch, set it to checked={false}.